# difference between the window.onload and (function() {})();

Tags: javascript

I'm actually seeing this script in javascript `(function() { //some code; })();` than using the `window.onload` what is the difference of the two? and which of the two is prefer to use?

Comment: First will execute when the script is 'rendered', `onload` will execute when the window has loaded full. If you googled them both then you could compare their behaviour and have the answer. Use whichever you want the behaviour of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Immediately Invoked Function Expression is invoked immediately.

A function assigned to `onload` is invoked when the *load* event fires (which is when the page and its dependencies have finished loading).

Answer (score -1):

The window.onload() waits for the window/page to be loaded before running it.

(function() {})(); run instantly if inserted into head section, before the DOM is constructed.